# Azure CLI az vm commands no longer creates an output on success

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

We are using an Azure CLI command to `start`/`stop`/`deallocate` VMs.

```
az vm start -g trg -n AzureCoE-VS1
```

This command used to give an output like

```html
{
 "endTime": "2018-08-03T10:20:56.271327+00:00",
 "error": null,
 "name": "1bc3b4ec-16b1-4f1f-a6a7-78fc23e62677",
 "startTime": "2018-08-03T10:20:46.849438+00:00",
 "status": "Succeeded"
}
```

However, we are no longer able to see this output as a result of which our application is breaking.

this used to work earlier.

Comment: Try to use `az vm start -g trg -n AzureCoE-VS1 --output json` or `az vm start -g trg -n AzureCoE-VS1 --debug` to see more details.

Comment: I have tried az vm start -g trg -n AzureCoE-VS1 --output json and az vm start -g trg -n AzureCoE-VS1 --output tsv etc but same output - blank. I have also tried the --verbose option which also doesnt return anything. Use --debug created way too much output than required, in any case it doesnt throw the required output as expected.

Comment: What region are your VM's running in?

Comment: The current VM i am testing with is in Southeast Asia

Comment: Upon troubleshooting, we figured that it works with Azure CLI App Version to v2.0.41. However on newer versions - Version 2.0.44 and above, it does not give an output.